# How to use Azure DevOps Pipelines Machine File Copy Using Environments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to move files from ADO to a VM. This VM is set up using "Environments" and tagged appropriately. I would like to copy those files to that VM using its environment name and tag. So far I've only found "Windows machine file copy" which requires storing a admin login. Is there a way to use the Environments instead of hardcoding a login?

Comment: What does your YAML look like? If you're running your deployment on an environment, you **don't need to copy build artifacts**, because the agent on each machine can download them.

Comment: well right now i don't have the yaml written because i'm not sure what to use. Could you send me a link to something that would help? It's literally just a file copy.

Comment: @c0d3w1thW1NG5 Common way to store passwords is Variable Group, in that way it will be secure and reusable in multiple places https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up the YAML pipeline like as below:

1. If you want to copy the build artifact files to the VM, reference below sample.

   - In the **`Build`** stage set up the jobs to build the source code, and publish the artifact files for use.
   - In the **`Deploy`** stage, when setting the **`deployment`** job with an **`environment`** on an VM, all steps in this job will be run on this VM. In the **`deployment`** job, at the very first step, it will automatically download the artifact files to the working directory on the VM.
   - Then you can use the CopyFiles task to the copy the artifact files to any accessible directory on the VM.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  . . .

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: 'Deployment'
    environment: '{EnvironmentName.ResourceName}'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy Files to: {Destination Directory}'
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
              Contents: '**'
              TargetFolder: '{Destination Directory}'
              CleanTargetFolder: true
```

2. If the files you want to copy the VM are the source files in the repository, reference below sample.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: 'Deployment'
    environment: '{EnvironmentName.ResourceName}'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: 'Copy Files to: {Destination Directory}'
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
              Contents: '**'
              TargetFolder: '{Destination Directory}'
              CleanTargetFolder: true
```

For more details, you can see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-kubernetes?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling for a while with setting up an **Azure Pipeline** to deploy **.Net Core service** to **VM**. I had the following requirements:

1. to use YAML files instead of classic UI
2. to deploy as a windows service not to IIS
3. to use stages in pipeline
4. I was using monorepo with the service residing in MyService folder
5. In addition I had an external NuGet feed
6. My solution consisted of several projects and I was building only one of them
7. appsettings.release.json was being replaced with the one persisted on the server to preserve settings

I was inspired by ***Bright Ran-MSFT*** answer and suggest my complete **azure-pipelines.yml** file

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - staging
  paths:
    include:
      - MyService

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  solution: "MyService/MyService.sln"
  buildPlatform: "Any CPU"
  buildConfiguration: "Release"

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            inputs:
              restoreSolution: "$(solution)"
              feedsToUse: "config"
              nugetConfigPath: "MyService/NuGet.Config"
          - task: VSBuild@1
            inputs:
              solution: "$(solution)"
              msbuildArgs: '/t:MyService:Rebuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\service_package"'
              platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
              configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"
          - task: VSTest@2
            inputs:
              platform: "$(buildPlatform)"
              configuration: "$(buildConfiguration)"
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\service_package'
              artifactName: "service_package"
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy'
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deployment
        displayName: 'Deployment'
        environment: 'MainDeployEnv.MY_VM_SERVER'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: CopyFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Copy Package to: C:\azservices\MyService\service'
                  inputs:
                    SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/service_package'
                    Contents: '**'
                    TargetFolder: 'C:\azservices\MyService\service\'
                    CleanTargetFolder: true
                - task: CopyFiles@2
                  displayName: 'Replace appsettings.release.json'
                  inputs:
                    SourceFolder: 'C:\azservices\MyService\settings'
                    Contents: 'appsettings.release.json'
                    TargetFolder: 'C:\azservices\MyService\service\'
                    OverWrite: true
```